# Recursive Relationship

Tags: database-design, relations

I have an application, which contains two Models `Question` and `Option`

- Each `Question` has many `Option`s
- Each `Option` may have many `Question`s (and this `Question` may have many sub `Option`s) so on and so forth.

Please help in how to achieve this relationship in database.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I would handle it like a normal many-to-many relationship, creating a table that holds question_id and option_id. Then, since you can have sub options, i would add another field containing the primary key of this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [question_option_rel] (
    [id] int IDENTITY (0,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [id_question] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [question]([id]),
    [id_option] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [option]([id]),
    [parent_option] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [question_option_rel]([id])
)
```

Comment: here does the question id mean that it is the sub question belonging to the option  or the option belongs to the main question?

Comment: I don't think i get what you're saying, but to be more clear: `[parent_option]` is a foreign key referring the primary key itself. When it's `null` it means that the record is a primary option (and you can have many of them). When it's valued, it means that the current record is a sub-option